# Creating a new vector, from 2 dataframes of different sizes

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames. Df A has 40 rows, Df B has 50.

Each row corresponds with a US state. The each has 2 columns: State name, and color.

I want to create a new vector (colorvector), of all colors of all 50 states. The default color should be dfB, however if the state is present in dfA, I would like the color to be taken from here instead.

I have tried:
 `colorvector <- as.vector(ifelse(dfA$state == dfB$st, 
                                dfA$color, dfB$color))`

I get the error:

> level sets of factors are different

I tried making dfA 50 rows long and just filling it in with NA's but that didn't work either.

Sorry if my formatting is off!

Comment: Have you tried converting your variables to character? `dfA$state <- as.character(dfA$state)`

Comment: Just did, no luck. Thank you for the reply though!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please include a subset of your data which can replicate the proglem to make this into a reproducible example [mre] it will help us to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this in a different way using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Make sure none of your variables are factors
dfA <- dfA %>%
mutate_if(is.factor,as.character)

dfB <- dfB %>%
mutate_if(is.factor,as.character)

# Join data and change any of the NA color values from dfB to corresponding values from dfA

    dfC <- left_join(dfA,dfB,by="State")

    dfC$color.y <- ifelse(is.na(dfC$color.y),dfC$color.x, dfC$color.y)

# Create colorvector
    colorvector <- as.vector(dfC$color.y)
```

dput for dfA:

```
dfA <- structure(list(State = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", 
"Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", 
"Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", 
"Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", 
"Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", 
"New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", 
"Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", 
"West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"), color = c("color_Alabama", 
"color_Alaska", "color_Arizona", "color_Arkansas", "color_California", 
"color_Colorado", "color_Connecticut", "color_Delaware", "color_Florida", 
"color_Georgia", "color_Hawaii", "color_Idaho", "color_Illinois", 
"color_Indiana", "color_Iowa", "color_Kansas", "color_Kentucky", 
"color_Louisiana", "color_Maine", "color_Maryland", "color_Massachusetts", 
"color_Michigan", "color_Minnesota", "color_Mississippi", "color_Missouri", 
"color_Montana", "color_Nebraska", "color_Nevada", "color_New Hampshire", 
"color_New Jersey", "color_New Mexico", "color_New York", "color_North Carolina", 
"color_North Dakota", "color_Ohio", "color_Oklahoma", "color_Oregon", 
"color_Pennsylvania", "color_Rhode Island", "color_South Carolina", 
"color_South Dakota", "color_Tennessee", "color_Texas", "color_Utah", 
"color_Vermont", "color_Virginia", "color_Washington", "color_West Virginia", 
"color_Wisconsin", "color_Wyoming")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

dput for dfB:

```
dfB <- structure(list(State = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", 
"Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", 
"Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", 
"Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", 
"Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", 
"New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", 
"Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), color = c("color_Alabama", 
"color_Alaska", "color_Arizona", "color_Arkansas", "color_California", 
"color_Colorado", "color_Connecticut", "color_Delaware", "color_Florida", 
"color_Georgia", "color_Hawaii", "color_Idaho", "color_Illinois", 
"color_Indiana", "color_Iowa", "color_Kansas", "color_Kentucky", 
"color_Louisiana", "color_Maine", "color_Maryland", "color_Massachusetts", 
"color_Michigan", "color_Minnesota", "color_Mississippi", "color_Missouri", 
"color_Montana", "color_Nebraska", "color_Nevada", "color_New Hampshire", 
"color_New Jersey", "color_New Mexico", "color_New York", "color_North Carolina", 
"color_North Dakota", "color_Ohio", "color_Oklahoma", "color_Oregon", 
"color_Pennsylvania", "color_Rhode Island", "color_South Carolina", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```